# Copying data from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I want to rearrange the data in the dataframe which is originally in following format

[3 rows for one project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSHLD.png)

I have extracted this using "rvest" package

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
projects<-NULL
thepage = read_html("https://www.99acres.com/search/project/buy/residential/pune?search_type=QS&search_location=SH&lstAcn=NPSEARCH&lstAcnId=9753976212484323&src=CLUSTER&preference=S&city=19&res_com=R&selected_tab=3&isvoicesearch=N&keyword=pune&strEntityMap=IiI%3D&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&searchform=1&price_min=null&price_max=null")

table = data.frame(html_table(x = thepage, fill = TRUE))
table = as.data.frame(t(table))
ResidentialProjects<-rbind(projects,setNames(table, names(table)))
```

I want all the details about 1 project (Real Estate Project Name) in one row.
I tried making a code for it as

```
newdf<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df=ResidentialProjects
projectName=""
count<-0
for(n in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[n,]$V1!=projectName){
    count = count+1
    projectName=df[n,]$V1
    newdf[count,c(1,2,3,4)]=df[n,c(1,2,3,4)]
    newdf[count,c(5,6,7)]=df[n+1,c(2,3,4)]
    newdf[count,c(8,9,10)]=df[n+2,c(2,3,4)]
  }else{
    print(n)
    next
  }
}
```

But its giving me a table of numbers like

[Output newdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQjU.png)

what is the problem? or any better option??

Comment: @Numb3rs...No!! i don't want to filter it. the main problem is if i am copying values in the specified row & column from one DF to other DF in specified row & column, why am i getting a set of numbers instead of the original string values..

Comment: Can you mention an example of your desired output?